# Why didn't the Celestials stop Thanos?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals

It's briefly mentioned in the movie *Eternals* that the Eternals are forbidden to interfere in human affairs. The terror created by Thanos and his 'Snap' are specifically referred to as events that the Eternals ignored.

The Eternals are answerable to the Celestials. Wouldn't the Celestials have acted to stop Thanos, given that half of the Celestials would have been wiped out by Thanos too?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259303/would-all-the-not-yet-emerged-celestials-like-tiamut-not-have-been-starved-50-d

Comment: doesn't answer the question. I'm asking about the Celestials not the Eternals.

Comment: @BCdotWEB no it doesn't - it talks about delaying emergence of one celestial, not genocide to their species.

Answer (score 5):

### The Celestials were beyond the power of the 'Snap'

Thanos, with his '[Snap](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Snap)', wiped out half of all life in the universe using the combined power of the Six Infinity Stones, also known as the ['Six Singularities'](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Stones).

The [Celestials](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Celestials), according to the text at the beginning of the movie *Eternals*, existed before the 'Singularities' came into existence.

> In the beginning... before the six Singularities and the dawn of Creation, came the CELESTIALS.

Given the indifference of the Celestials to Thanos' schemes, it would appear that having originated before the existence of the Infinity Stones, the Celestials were simply beyond the power of the 'Snap'.

Answer (score -5):

celestials were in their own universes, right? and the celestials are only able to rise after the eternals basically vanished a planet. Because the celestials are in their own universes and planets, I don't think they go into other universes. otherwise, it would've stated that in the movie.

Comment: I did not get any of this from the movie - no mention of other universes.  Other Celestials have already appeared in the MCU (particularly Guardians of the Galaxy 1 & 2) - Knowhere, Ego, Eson the Searcher (seen wielding the power stone in a Guardians of the Galaxy flashback).  Why would being born from a planet make them in "their own universe"?